# JavaScript fileWatcher

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I am developing a web application (intranet) and it is mandatory to watch a specific folder, for example c:\docs, for inserted files. I would like to do that through JavaScript in order to detect each time the client inserts file into specific directory.

Comment: You cannot watch the local file system from within a browser.

Comment: Can i do that through activex?

Comment: No. Bowsers do not allow *any* access to system resources from within a web page. It's a security risk, so cannot be done. A web page always runs in a very restricted [sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)).

Comment: Thx, my app is a document management system and i want to get the scanned docs of each user. Twain is one solution but my company has to pay for it. Do you think that i have other alternatives?

Comment: Send the files to a shared drive on the sever and have server side script watch that directory. If you want complicated, there are plenty of examples all over the Internet on how to use .NET's [`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). If you want quick and dirty, use a scheduled task that runs a small VBScript that [polls the directory every so often](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh(v=vs.84).aspx) and writes to a database.

Comment: Thx again for your rapid replay, i think filesystemwatcher could be an option but we have to find which user uploads the file, for which department and many other things. I am thinking that it could be a solution if i implement filesystemwatcher in global asax.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is intended to run in a background service. global.asax only runs when there is a request going on. You'd have to use a long-running thread and asynchronous programming to use its potential. Look [here](http://www.programminginterviews.info/2011/05/how-to-monitor-file-system-changes.html). A scheduled task that runs every minute and checks for new files is the easier alternative, IMHO.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but i need to know which userid did the scan and many other things that need to know about the scanned file. I think that i have to go to Twain solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your own application using [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It has very safe methods to handle user models and for handling files.

Question is, do you want a web-based interface for users to manage their documents, or do you want to monitor documents as and when people modify directly in the file system?

For the former, I'd say django is a very good option to build your own app in no time.

**EDIT**

For the latter, you can use node.js. Here's an interesting project that could get you started - https://github.com/mikeal/watch

Comment: Thx for your replay. We want the users to upload pdf from scanner files through drag n drop and we have implemented that, which is the easy part, but we want also when the user uses the scanner to scan a document to uploaded to the web page. So we were trying to find a way to monitor the folder https://github.com/twolfson/File-Watcher/#readme or through http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Oh that's nice. I was just about to suggest node.js. Its pretty powerful.

Comment: Can you provide me any link with a full example? Thx in advance